# Relation between Zariski continuous and Euclidean continuous in Affine $\Bbb{C}^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was bit confused by the relation of Zariski continuous function and Euclidean continuous function. Does one implies another on $\Bbb{C}^n$.

---

I came up an example $\sin(2\pi z):\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$  with $0$ closed in both Zariski and Euclidean topology, but $f^{-1}(0) = \Bbb{Z}$ which is closed in Euclidean topology but not Zariski topology therefore it is not Zariski continuous is my understanding correct?

Conversely, is there an example that Zariski continuous needs not to be Euclidean continuous?

Comment: Yes, your example is indeed a Euclidean continuous function that is not Zariski continuous.

Comment: The function $f(z):=z$ if $z\ne0$ and $f(0):=1$ is a Zariski continuous function that is not Euclidean continuous.

Comment: Indeed, Zariski continuous functions are either constant or has finite fibers.

Comment: got it,  thank you Kenta S , clear now

Comment: @KentaS if you're going to answer, please do so in the answer box below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following proposition provides an easy way to check for Zariski continuity:

**Proposition:** A nonconstant function $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is Zariski continuous if and only if it has finite fibers, i.e., $f^{-1}(z)$ is finite for any $z\in\mathbb C$.

**Proof:** Remember that the Zariski topology on $\mathbb C$ is the co-finite topology, i.e., a proper subset $F\subsetneq\mathbb C$ is closed if and only if it is finite. Thus, the function $f$ is Zariski continuous if and only if for any finite subset $F\subsetneq\mathbb C$ we have $f^{-1}(F)$ is finite. This is clearly equivalent to each fiber being finite.

---

For example, your function $\sin(2\pi z)\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is indeed Euclidean continuous but not Zariski continuous since the preimage of $0$, which is $\mathbb Z$, is infinite.

On the other hand,
$$f(z):=\begin{cases}z&\text{if }z\ne0\\1&\text{if }z=0\end{cases}$$
is an example of a function not continuous in the Euclidean topology but has finite fibers.

Comment: Very intuitive example thank you